# Relocating an anonymous prefix keymap

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, ibuffer, prefix-keys

ibuffer uses <kbd>/</kbd> as a prefix key for filter commands, like *ibuffer-filter-by-name* (<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>).

As an evil user, I wanted to use a different prefix, since evil uses <kbd>/</kbd> for searching.

I use <kbd>space</kbd> as a leader-key, so I decided to put the filter commands behind <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.

The ibuffer <kbd>/</kbd> prefix is an anonymous keymap, so I had to bind my new key to the result of a *lookup-key* call:

```
(bind-map-for-mode-inherit ivan/ibuffer-leader-map ivan/leader-map
  :major-modes (ibuffer-mode)
  :bindings
  ("/" (lookup-key ibuffer-mode-map "/")))  ; <= here
```

It works, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

I say it's an anonymous keymap because I wasn't able to find any variable bound to it. Running `(lookup-key ibuffer-mode-map "/")` just prints out the keymap body:

```
(keymap
 (92 . ibuffer-clear-filter-groups)
 ...
 (109 . ibuffer-filter-by-used-mode))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the answer is yes, you are right.  And there is no cleaner way to deal with it - but see below, for one suggestion.

I'd suggest filing an enhancement request that Emacs add a variable for this keymap: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

You can of course define your own map variable for this, basing its value on the current `ibuffer.el` code.  But that won't automatically pick up future changes to the Ibuffer code.

In general, I think it is a good idea for prefix keys to have associated keymap variables.  That makes it easy for users to, e.g., move such a map to a different prefix key.

Comment: I liked your suggestion. I just filed an enhancement request.